# Hide empty group in WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm trying to further customize build-in capability of WPF ListBox for showing items in groups.

In short, I want to hide Group's container (and Group's title altogether) if all items inside group are collapsed (`Visibility` property).

First, I have very simple class City that represent single Item. This class include `Shown` property. Inside `ItemContainerStyle` I simply have `DataTrigger` that set `Visibility` to `Collapsed` if value of this property is `False`.

```
class City : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool m_Shown = true;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public bool Shown
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Shown;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Shown = value;
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Shown"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

This is how I add sample cities, add Group description and all work fine.

```
m_cities = new List<City>
{
    new City() { Name = "Berlin", Country = "Germany" },
    new City() { Name = "Milano", Country = "Italy" },
    new City() { Name = "Frankfurt", Country = "Germany" },
    new City() { Name = "Rome", Country = "Italy" }
};

ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(m_cities);
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Country"));
Cities = view; // <-- Binds to ItemsSource of ListBox
```

I tried in several ways to automatically hide Group if there are no more items visible in it (all are collapsed), but all without luck.

One way is to repeat last 3 lines in code above and this works, but I noticed slowdown with this method and listbox must work fast for user.

Bellow is one of my examples and this actually worked for hiding, but I can't bring group to be visible anymore after that. I tried with converters and similar, but I can't get group **visible again**.

```
<ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ActualHeight" Value="20">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListBox.GroupStyle>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6):

A bit (!) late with this, but hopefully it might help someone else in the future.

Inside the control template of most (all?) `GroupItem` styles is an `ItemsPresenter` that is used to host and display the child items that belong to the group. It stands to reason that, **if all of the child items are collapsed, this `ItemsPresenter` will have a height of zero.**

Therefore, you can add a trigger to the control template based on this condition, and set the `Visibility` of the whole group item accordingly. A normal property trigger doesn't seem to work, but a data trigger will. Something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <StackPanel x:Name="Root">
        ...
        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" />
        ...
    </StackPanel>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ItemsPresenter}" Value="0">
            <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You will need to name the root element of the control template (in this example it's a `StackPanel` element I've named "Root") and also the `ItemsPresenter` element (I've just called it "ItemsPresenter"). Obviously the root element might be a different type, and you can use whichever names you like.

You were on the right track, but you needed to bind to the `ActualHeight` of the `ItemsPresenter`, and it needed to be a data trigger not a normal property trigger.